# Bower no Visual Studio 2015

Tags: asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, bower, npm

Baixei Visual Studio 2015 Community e fui testar pra ver se estava tudo Ok. Mas não está, quando crio um projeto Web ASP.NET MVC 5, o arquivo bower.json não 'oferece' o Intellisense como mostra em alguns tutoriais. Alguém tem ideia de como corrigir esse 'bug'?

Answer (score 0):

Tente essa extensão:

[Pacote de intellisense](https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/65748cdb-4087-497e-a394-2e3449c8e61e)

Eu testei no meu computador e funcionou.

Comment: Ela só serve para o VS 2013, o que eu estou usando e o 2015.